# Prompt for mathematical expression of two variables, followed by evaluation

Tags: ti-basic

I would like the user to be prompted to input an expression "E" like `2X` or `Y+3X^2` or `√(X+Y)`. Then I would like to evaluate "E" with specific values for `X` and `Y` and store the output.

Here's a high-level idea of what I want to achieve:

```
Prompt X, Y
Prompt E # expression in terms of X, Y
eval(E,X,Y)→O # evaluation of expression E given values of X, Y
```